# How to segment users by country location efficiently for an application?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I have an application that deals with sensitive data.
The law asks me to save users data in databases in their respective countries.

I am using GCP - Cloud Functions and MongoDB Atlas to save user data.
I am aware that MongoDB offers `Zones` in sharded clusters to segment users by location which should be working fine.

For now, what i have done a simple geolocating request from the IP address in my `python` backend that tells me the country where the request comes from such as :

```
{'ip': '86.237.55.104', 'ip_number': '1458386792', 'ip_version': 4, 'country_name': 'France', 'country_code2': 'FR', 'isp': 'Orange S.A.', 'response_code': '200', 'response_message': 'OK'}
```

but if the user is travelling it's not that relevant.

- Should i save it only once at the account creation for example ?
- How can i check without asking for the national ID card, only from the code if that's even possible ?

Thanks a lot in advance for any lead

Answer (score 0):

From a technical POV, you can definitely use the Atlas Zoned sharding capability, and shard by geo-location.

The question of when to assign the geo-location to the user is a legal one, not a technical one. In most of the cases I'm familiar with, the location is either assigned given the user address / preferences - but specific differences between GDPR and CCPA requirements might render this solution a violations, so I suggest you take it up with your legal dep.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i understand and agree with you ! 
However my question is actually technical, because i already know what my requirements are regarding GDPR / CCPA, i simply don't know how to get the "real" information about `what / when` to save user geo-location to comply with the law.
I mean i don't want to ask them for their national ID cards... I would like a coding way to do this efficiently without the legal representative come to me and tell "hey you save this user data in Switzerland but he is now living in Belgium. "

Comment: If the person that can tell you that something is correct or not is someone from legal, then you have a legal issue, not a technical one :)

Comment: I agree, but how to avoid or answer such question is a technical issue, my initial question